# Не правильно выводятся данные о процессоре через linq

Tags: c#, linq, инспекция-кода

Вот пример:

```
private static ManagementObjectSearcher Processor = new 
ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");

var ProcessorName = Processor.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().Select(gob => 
(string)gob["Name"] + gob["Manufacturer"]).ToList();
```

`[Name - Процессор + Manufacturer - Производитель]`

Записываю в `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`

```
sb.AppendFormat("Процессор: ", ProcessorName.Select(s => $"{s}"));
```

На выходе получается ошибка:

> Процессор:
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.String,System.String]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибки нет, вы пытаетесь напечатать, как я понимаю объект, который возвращает Select (IEnumerable в вашем случае)

Попробуйте превратить коллекцию в строку таким образом:

`string.Join(", ", ProcessorName)`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Comment: `.Select(s => $"{s}")` избыточно.

Comment: @Squidward, В каком смысле избыточно?

Comment: @GooliveR, попробуйте просто `string.Join(", ", ProcessorName)` Результат будет таким же. Поправлю в ответе тоже